# Same indirect formula working differently in different computers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've created a sheet that would take the raw data from the same workbook and put it in correct order, format and do some calculations on it before it is reflected to the main table. However, yesterday when another user opened the workbook, the formulas which include indirect returned errors for the user while when I open it, it is working fine.

Here is a sample formula:

```
=IFERROR(TIME(LEFT(INDIRECT("RawData!R" & ROW()+16 & "C" & COLUMN(); 0); 2); MID(INDIRECT("RawData!R" & ROW()+16 & "C" & COLUMN(); 0); 4; 2); 0); "")
```

The formula is supposed to result in "9:00" from the target cell which is "9:00-9:15". For me, it is giving me 9:00 but for the other user, it is giving an error.

Looking further into the problem, when I entered N() outside the indirects, the cell showed 0:00 for the other user, meaning that the indirect is not returning an error but a text which is causing an error in the time function.

While I can fix the issue by using Value() outside the indirect, I want to understand why this is happening to make my formulas more compatible. Why would indirect return a text on one PC (the user) and a number on another PC (mine)?

Comment: What kind of error does the other user get?
Do you and the other user have the same language settings (i.e. '.' as decimal separator ...)?

Comment: Step through the formula using the Formula Evaluation tool on the errant computer to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This heavily looks like a formatting/locale problem to me: check the values of the cells and the way they are formatted. Also check their type (is it a time value or a string value which looks like a time value). In many cases the latter might be derived from the alignment (Excel has the habit of aligning numbers/dates/times to the right, while strings generally are aligned to the left).